# Scanner scans garbage lines

Tags: scanner

My Canon CanoScan liDE 120 scannr suddenly started scan pictures with garbage lines:

[image]

Can't find it is software or hardware issue. What kind of problem it might be?

Comment: Many scanners have a calibration area on the glass that you need to leave uncovered so that it can make a white-point adjustment based on the intensity of the lamp on a known white color. IF you cover this, you can interfere with the adjustment.

Comment: Looks like the light source is out of sync with what the software expects. Some scanners use different light colors instead of a color sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Try powering it off, unplug, wait 30 seconds, make sure lid is closed, re-plug directly into wall (no power strips, extension cords, etc), power-up.

If this doesn't work, try re-calibrating the scanner.

Also clean the glass per [Canon's instructions](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART163377&actp=RSS):

> Clean off the dirt and dust that adheres to the exterior, document
>   glass and document cover of the scanner during the course of ordinary
>   operation using the following procedures.
>
> 1. Detach the USB cable from the computer.
> 2. When cleaning the document cover or document glass, dampen a clean, soft cloth with water and wring the cloth well. Use the well-wrung
>      cloth to gently remove dirt and dust. Then, thoroughly remove any
>      moisture or water vapor with a soft, dry cloth. Be particularly
>      careful to remove any traces of dirt or liquid when wiping the
>      document glass.
>      *Moisture left on the document glass or cover may damage photographs and other documents as well as produce poor results.
>
> *Do not dampen the connectors, ports or other metallic components on the scanner's back panel. Immediately remove any moisture that
>   contacts these components by wiping them with a dry cloth.
>
> *Do not use an excessively wet cloth or apply a liquid to any portion of the scanner. Any moisture that enters the interior, the underside
>   of the document glass or the sensors may degrade image quality and
>   lead to malfunctions.
>
> *Never use substances containing alcohol, thinner or benzene on the equipment. Use of these substances may deform, discolor or dissolve
>   the casing.
>
> *Do not press heavily on the document glass when cleaning.

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART158063 . You're using someone's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on [SU]. Remember to always add prominent attribution and appropriate block quoting when using other sources. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I did give attribution. The first part of the answer is my own. the second part is from Canon, as I stated.

Comment: No you didn't. Please read the link in my comment. You need to include a link to the Canon material and also block quote it.

Comment: I'll fix it for you this time. Please pay attention in future.